# TypeError: 'NoneType' - Selection Sort on Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to make a selection sort using python, I just recently learned python following the book "Python Crash Course" then now I'm reading the book "grokking algorithms"

I pretty much understood the selection sort algorithm but I just can't figure out why I'm getting a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

So the way I test it is to populate my array using `random.randint(1, 101)` and `range(0,11)`, what I can't figure out is why python can't interpret it as an integer? since both function returns an integer. The error seems to happen when I do the `new_array.append(arr.pop(smallest))`.

see my full code below. (I'm using Python 3)

```
import random

def find_smallest(arr):
    """Return the index of the smallest value in an array"""
    smallest = arr[0]
    smallest_index = 0

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallest_index = i
        return smallest_index

def selection_sort(arr):
    """sort an array by storing smallest value to new array 1 by 1"""
    new_array = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallest = find_smallest(arr)
        new_array.append(arr.pop(smallest))
    return new_array


my_array = []
for i in range(0, 11):
    my_array.append(random.randint(1, 101))
    print(my_array[i])

sorted_array = selection_sort(my_array)
for i in range(len(sorted_array)):
    print(sorted_array[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an indentation problem in your `find_smallest()` function

Consider

```
def find_smallest(arr):
    """Return the index of the smallest value in an array"""
    smallest = arr[0]
    smallest_index = 0

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallest:
            smallest = arr[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index  # <--- this is the line
```

Note that the `return` statement is indented differently than in your code.

To debug such problems you should notice that `arr.pop()` requires an integer or a list of integers as an argument, so you could insert

```python
 assert(smallest is not None)
```

above the failing line `new_array.append(arr.pop(smallest))` and confirm that assertion is triggered, then check at which iteration this happens replacing assert statement with

```python
 assert(smallest is not None), "Array length is %d" % len(arr)
```

This would trigger an exception

```
 AssertionError: Array length is 1
```

Then you would know that you need to check what does your `find_smallest` function return when its argument is an array of length 1.

Comment: thank you so much! I understand it now since the return statement is incorrectly indented the way the script works is that it will only return when the "if statement" has been met. thanks, I appreciate it how you include debugging steps for such problem. you're awesome!